# Woocommerce - Display product excerpt in Orders page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show the product's excerpt in the Orders page. I spent several hours trying to find a solution but nothing.

I already show the image & the title of the product (Thanks to @helgatheviking & this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813815/show-products-image-in-orders-page-woocommerce/30814596?noredirect=1#comment51047277_30814596)) , but I can't get the excerpt to show. This is my code:

```
 <div id="order-column" class="my_account_orders">
   <div class="wrap">
     <?php
       foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
       $order = wc_get_order( );
       $order->populate( $customer_order );

       foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
           $product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );
           $product->get_image();
           $product->get_title();             
       }         
       $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
   ?>
    <div class="orders-wrap">
      <div class="preview">
        <div class="image">
          <div class="image-wrap"><?php echo $product->get_image(); ?></div>
        </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="details">
        <h3 class="name"><a title="View Order" href="<?php echo $order->get_view_order_url(); ?>"><?php echo $product->get_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <h4 class="subtitle"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h4>              
      </div>
    </div>
```

The excerpt should appear in `subtitle`.
I have checked and tried the suggestions in these threads:
[Woocommerce - description in products page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479712/woocommerce-description-in-products-page)
[Adding a product description to the woocommerce cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23500167/adding-a-product-description-to-the-woocommerce-cart-page)

Comment: Always worth taking a look at how WooCommerce itself is [displaying data](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/short-description.php#L22). And for subtitles, take a look at the [plugin I wrote](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kia-subtitle/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it. `the_excerpt` can only be used in combination with `the_post()` as it depends on the global `$post` object. But this pretty much reassembles what happens inside it.

```
<h4 class="subtitle"><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $product->post->post_excerpt ); ?></h4>
```

Comment: That was it! Thank u very much!

Comment: Also `get_the_excerpt( $product->id );` should do the same.

Comment: Sorry no. It takes no arguments, in contact to i.e. `get_the_content()` and `get_the_title()`. Check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt

Answer (score 5):

A bit late but always use this here:

```
get_the_excerpt( $product->get_id() );
```

The other solution from Johan Palmfjord will work but WooCommerce says that you never should access the product data directly.